# EWS with Powershell: "The property has an invalid value"

Tags: powershell, exchangewebservices

I am trying to loop through mailboxes via EWS/Powershell to read some properties of the mails in the inbox. This is working for most mailboxes - but not for all. I am using paging to loop through the results:

```
$moreItems=$true
$Offset=100
$pageSize=100
while($moreItems)
{
$itemView = new-object Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ItemView($pageSize,$Offset,[Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.OffsetBasePoint]::Beginning)

...

$mails = $currentFolder.FindItems($itemView)


foreach($mail in $mails)
{
   #add-contnet -path "output.txt" -value $mail.subject
}

$itemView.Offset += $mails.Items.Count
if ($mails.MoreAvailable -eq $false)
{
      $MoreItems = $false
}
if ($MoreItems)
{
    $Offset += $pageSize
}
}
```

As I said, this is working perfect for some mailboxes - with some it runs into an exception:

"The property has an invalid value."

This error happens in this code line:

```
$mails = $currentFolder.FindItems($itemView)
```

As you can see, I am writing the subject of all mails into a txt file. Depending on the pagesize and the offset the output file lists more or less subjects (mail items). e.g. if the inbox has 2000 items, it would list 1008 items in the output file, when I set the pagesize to 1000 and it would list 1907, if I set it to 100 and so on. Anyhow I always get the exception (but again, only for some mailboxes).

Any ideas / any hints how to dig deeper?

Comment: what is $currentFolder?

Comment: Check this link out, not sure if it will help. If so then there are no problem with your script, it is just the way PS works. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/86587dc9-b602-417c-9108-ba259cd1f4be/ews-getitem-request-fielduri-calendaruid-property-has-an-invalid-value

Answer (score 0):

found the answer: it turned out that it chrashed when other items than ipm.note resided in the mailbox - e.g. a meeting request. I did a searchfilter to filter only for ipm.note and passed it to the finditems() method - this worked ...

Yan